# Regex not latin alphabet - fail for mixed input

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need to stop the users to enter text using alphabet different from the Latin one (aka english).

I am using the following function based on a regex but I have some issues:

1. The validation fails if the input is empty
2. The validation pass if the input is mixed for example `aaaaффффф`

I solve the first point using a simple `if` anyway it would be nice if the regex take care of this case too 
The second point is what I care more.

```
function validate_latin(v){
    var regex = new RegExp("[\u0000-\u007F\u0080-\u00FF]");
    if (v != '') {
        return regex.test(v);
    }
    return true;
}
```

p.s.
I googled and found other similar question but none is complete or cover this sceniario

Comment: Use anchors and a quantifier. That will only allow the ascii characters specified. This is only looking for 1 ascii character then anything else is allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: like chris85 said, if your latin sub-pattern is working then it is just `/^[\u0000-\u007F\u0080-\u00FF]+$/`

Comment: @sweaver2112 thx I confirm this is working fine, if you can put it in answer I will be glad to accept it

Answer (score 0):

if your Latin subpattern is working for you, the solution is straightforward.  `^` and `$` anchors will prevent partial matching (whole string/line must match), and the `+`, which means 'one or more', disallows the empty string:

```
/^[\u0000-\u007F\u0080-\u00FF]+$/
```